# How to map key/value pairs of a "map" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, data-structures

How to map key/value pairs of a "map" in JavaScript:

```
var map = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3};

alert(JSON.stringify(map));
```

I need to get a mapper containing key/value pair on each iteration:

```
// ["a_1", "b_2", "c_3"]
map.map((key, value) => key + "_" + value);
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is not a `Map` object. It's just a regular object. So, use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and then use `map` on the key value pair:

```js
const map = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3};
const mapped = Object.entries(map).map(([k,v]) => `${k}_${v}`);
console.log(mapped);
```

`Object.entries` returns:

```
[["a",1],["b",2],["c",3]]
```

Then loop through each of those inner arrays and create the string using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

---

If you have a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object, use [`Array.from(map)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to get the entries of the map and use the second parameter of `Array.from` to go over each entry and create the desired string

```
Array.from(map, ([k,v]) => `${k}_${v}`)
```

Comment: this is wrong if the actual data structure is a Map, this is the solution for an object

Comment: For using this in TypeScript, you can cast it as any. `(Object.entries(map) as any).map(([k, v]) => \`${k}_${v}\`)`

Answer (score 14):

It's not a map, it's an object. (You might consider using a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), though.)

To get its properties as key/value pairs, you can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), which you can then apply `map` to:

```
map = Object.entries(map).map(([key, value]) => key + "_" + value);
```

`Object.entries` is relatively new, but easily polyfilled for older environments.

Live Example:

```js
var map = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3};
map = Object.entries(map).map(([key, value]) => key + "_" + value);
console.log(map);
```

---

Or, using a `Map`, you can use its built-in `entries` method, which returns an iterable, passing it into `Array.from` and using `Array.from`'s mapping callback:

```js
var map = new Map([
  ["a", 1],
  ["b", 2],
  ["c", 3]
]);
map = Array.from(map.entries(), ([key, value]) => key + "_" + value);
console.log(map);
```

(Or expand the iterable into an array — `[...map.entries()]` — and use `map` on it, but the above avoids a temporary throw-away array.)

In both cases, I'm using destructuring in the parameter list of the arrow function, which receives an array in `[key, value]` format.

Answer (score 2):

You could take the entries of the object and join the key/value pairs.

```js
var map = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 },
    result = Object.entries(map).map(a => a.join('_'));
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This definitely produce the requested output and is extremely easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys` which will give an array of the keys present in that object , then use array map method on that array and access the value of each key and create a string

```js
var map = {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3
};

let neObj = Object.keys(map).map(item => `${item}_${map[item]}`)

console.log(neObj)
```

Comment: you've used ES6 syntax, so `Object.entries()` is a better solution.

Comment: is that the reason of downvoting?

Comment: @Alnitak bizarre reason to downvote all our working solutions. Object.keys is ECMAScript 5.1 and has more browser support, Object.entries is ES7 and doesn't work in IE.

Comment: @Dominic  The OP used an arrow function - IE support is clearly not a factor.

Comment: @Dominic either way, there's actually a sound technical reason to recommend against the `Object.keys` method, and that is since the values are not passed to the `.map` call directly the callback must form a closure over the original object to obtain them, which means it has to be in the same lexical scope.  This prevents the use of a re-usable function to perform the resulting operation on the pairs.

Comment: @Dominic this, incidentally, is why `.map` itself always passes the original array as the third callback parameter, so that callback functions outside the lexical scope can still access that array and don't have to form a closure over it.  However, that falls down when the array you're passing (in this case the `Object.keys()` array doesn't hold all of the information that the callback requires.

Answer (score 0):

First [0] is for position elements and second [0] is for name key or [1] for value etc.

```
console.log([...map][0][0])
```

### Example:

```
var map = {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3
};
console.log([...map][0][0] + "_" + [...map][0][1])
```

Output:

```
a_1
```

Answer (score 0):

Or the most simplest form would be,

```
let list = document.querySelector('ol');
let listitems = list.childNodes;
var list_items_array = Array.from(listitems);

let node_type_map = new Map();

node_type_map.set(1, 'Element');
node_type_map.set(2, 'Attribute');
node_type_map.set(3, 'Text Node');
node_type_map.set(8, 'comment');
node_type_map.set(9, 'Document Itself');
node_type_map.set(10, 'Doctype');

list_items_array.forEach(item => {
    console.log(node_type_map.get(item.nodeType));
})
```